# python cocoa shared application with a timer

Tags: python, cocoa, macos

I would like to have an interval timer within a cocoa "shared application".  I have a python cocoa application (not sure it is the right terminology) using `PyObjCTools`.

```
app = App.sharedApplication()
ticker=Ticker()
timer=NSTimer.timerWithTimeInterval_target_selector_userInfo_repeats(0.1, ticker, 'tick', None, False)
## how do I attach the Timer to the shared application???
AppHelper.runEventLoop()
```

How do I integrate the Timer within the application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't associate the timer with the shared application. You associate the timer with the run loop.  Do

```
NSRunLoop.currentRunLoop.addTimer_forMode(timer,NSRunLoopCommonModes)
```

(sorry if the syntax is not correct as a Python code... ) See [the documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSRunLoop_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000321-addTimer_forMode_).